# Where should I put util functions - OOP best practices

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I wonder, where general (or util functions) should be placed?

For example:

```
public class Credit {
    private Integer _duration;              
    private Double _interestRate;           
    private Integer _creditSum;     
    private PaymentStream _paymentStream;
    private Date _openDate;         
}
```

PaymentStream impements  strategy pattern for gettin paymentList.

Question:
I have a construnctor (duration, interestRate, creditSum, paymentStream, openDate). But I also want followin functions:

- getCreditDuration(creditSum, monthlyPayments, interestRate)
- getCreditSum(montlyPayment, interestRate, duration)
- etc

Obviously, they can't be on credit instance, as I don't have enough info for a constructor. So where they should be placed?

**Added**: I've also need to store all the calculations (getCreditDuration, etc) into db. So, if this is static functions returning double(int) I can't image of a good way to store them into DB. What object should I save?

Requirments are: user can choose between Duration calculation and Credit sum calculation (and etc.) There are separate views for calculations. Every time user click "Calculate button" calculation result must be persisted into DB. User can has a view with all calculation, where he can click any item.

For ex (с means value is calculated):

```
Sum      Duration Interest Payment 
10000    2 yrs    12%      1000(с)    -> opens view to calculate monthly payment
12000(с) 3 yrs    10%      1200       -> opens view to calculate credit sum
```

Comment: You mean whenever anyone performs that calculation, every single time, no special cases, a record must be written to a database? Seems a very odd requirement. My instinct is that persistence (for example for audit purposes) belongs in a separate class, one which calls these static methods. Please explain your requirement a bit more and perhaps we can find a better answer

Comment: Pass in an object to collaborate with, which provides the functionality you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stateless methods (all data they work on is passed as a parameter) whose logic is clearly tied the concepts of the Credit object. So one possibility is just to make them static methods of the Credit class.

Comment: You could make them non-member functions, putting them in an anonymous namespace in the cpp file, rather than cluttering up the class declaration.